# how can i use 'CASE WHEN' syntax in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to manipulate query result

[Original Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnIC3.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnHCG.png)

original query is

```
SELECT grantee,
               privilege
          FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
         WHERE OWNER = 'BIZOWNFO'
           AND TABLE_NAME = 'TB_AT_CASHREC_DTLS';
```

I want to make result like this query

```
select grantee,
       (case when privilege = 'SELECT' then 'O' end ) as SEL,
       (case when privilege = 'UPDATE' then 'O' end ) as UPD,
       (case when privilege = 'INSERT' then 'O' end ) as INS,
       (case when privilege = 'DELETE' then 'O' end ) as DEL
FROM
(
SELECT grantee,
   privilege
FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE OWNER = 'BIZOWNFO'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'TB_AT_CASHREC_DTLS'
) group by grantee;
```

but it didn't work

i want to know how to do it.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle? (Remove the unrelated tags.)

Comment: It's the GROUP BY that causes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need the `GROUP BY` clause with pivoting logic:

```sql
SELECT
    grantee AS "ROLE",
    MAX(CASE WHEN privilege = 'SELECT' THEN 'O' END) AS "SELECT",
    MAX(CASE WHEN privilege = 'UPDATE' THEN 'O' END) AS "UPDATE",
    MAX(CASE WHEN privilege = 'INSERT' THEN 'O' END) AS "INSERT",
    MAX(CASE WHEN privilege = 'DELETE' THEN 'O' END) AS "DELETE"
FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE
    OWNER = 'BIZOWNFO' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TB_AT_CASHREC_DTLS'
GROUP BY
    grantee;
```

Comment: that is what i really want ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should remove the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SQL> SELECT grantee,
  2         (CASE WHEN privilege = 'SELECT' THEN 'O' END) AS sel,
  3         (CASE WHEN privilege = 'UPDATE' THEN 'O' END) AS upd,
  4         (CASE WHEN privilege = 'INSERT' THEN 'O' END) AS ins,
  5         (CASE WHEN privilege = 'DELETE' THEN 'O' END) AS del
  6    FROM (SELECT grantee, privilege
  7            FROM dba_tab_privs
  8           WHERE     owner = 'MIKE'
  9                 AND table_name = 'TEST');

GRANTEE                        S U I D
------------------------------ - - - -
KCDBA                          O
SCOTT                              O

SQL>
```